# JPA for child steps via Join Table

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following data in two tables in my database (additional columns omitted for clarity).  This basically represents a directed graph, with child steps present in their own table.  Foreign keys are laid out as expected.

```
mysql> select * from template_step;
+----+-----------+
| id | step_name |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Step 1    |
|  2 | Step 2    |
|  3 | Step 3    |
|  4 | Step 4    |
+----+-----------+

mysql> select * from next_steps;
+-----------------+--------------+
| current_step_id | next_step_id |
+-----------------+--------------+
|               1 |            2 |
|               1 |            3 |
|               3 |            4 |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I then have an Entity class that represents the first table, and I'm trying to figure out the correct JPA setup for exposing the child steps as a list in this class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template_step")
public class TemplateStepRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="step_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="next_steps", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="next_step_id", referencedColumnName="current_step_id")})
    private List<TemplateStepRecord> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Those annotations on `children` are obviously incorrect, as I'm getting an error like this:

```
Unable to find column with logical name: current_step_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(template_step) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

I'm not sure what to put here, nor if any additional annotations should be present on that or the `OneToMany` annotation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional mapping.
See https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/one-to-many-bidirectional.html

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template_step")
public class TemplateStepRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "step_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="templateStepRecord")
   private final List<TemplateNextStepRecord> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "next_steps")
public class TemplateNextStepRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name="next_step_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="current_step_id")
    private TemplateStepRecord templateStepRecord; 
}
```

Comment: What would the code for that getter look like then?

Comment: @StevenM.Wurster Please check again. I have added action implementations. And the result looks like your table

Comment: I'm not 100% sure my table layout matches your implementation.  That is, only the TemplateStepRecord class has an auto-generated ID.  The IDs in the next_steps table are purely foreign key relations to that table.  I didn't think I would need an equivalent to TemplateNextStepRecord, but I will try creating one without the auto-generated IDs and seeing how that goes.

Comment: You can simply remove the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) annotation` . You will have to set the ID before adding it to the collection

Comment: Wait, I misunderstood / misinterpreted what you wrote there, and I think I got it working.  I'm not thrilled with the next_steps table having a class representation; is there any way to avoid that?